# .NET c# - Customize Display Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

.NET MVC Application EF code first, using Identity 2

Each application user belongs to a specific user_type (ApplicationUser.user_type). (the application uses Identity roles too, but they are completely independent of this user_type). 
also, I am extensively using Display attribute on properties of models and viewmodels with:

```
[Display(Name="some literal"]
public string someProperty { get; set; }
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.someProperty)
```

or
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.someProperty)

But now I am required to, in some cases, display different things if the logged-in user is of a specific user_type ("Client").

What would be the best way to implement this? I am guessing maybe its possible to customize the Display attribute so that it accepts a parameter "userType", so I could decorate the properties with something like:

```
[Display(Name="This will be shown to users with user_type: Client", UserType="Client"]
[Display(Name="This will be shown to everyone else"]
public int myProperty { get; set; }
```

or something like that... but I have no idea how to do it... any help is appreciated

Comment: By user type do you mean role? If you are using identity you could use roles to change what is output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems that you are trying to put too much logic/responsibility in one place.

I recon you would manage to come up with something to deal with this scenario, but, if you do, you'll risk ending up with an inter tangled property which behaviour will depend on all sorts of external parameters. The more you'll add, the more complex it will become. That can be hard to maintain.

I am not fond of "keep it simple" but I think it does apply here, by keeping it simple in maintenance.

IMO you have a couple of options to help you out:

- create a complete new view and a model for this client page
- add a propery to your (view)model which contains the string.
- add the string to the page and handle it with razor.
- use a viewbag or similar temp data container

So, to sum it: I dont think expanding the Display attribute would be the way to go here and consider one (or another) of the methods mentioned above.